# C# Formsauthentication timeout in web.config overrules manual ticket timeout?

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms-authentication

I have a testproject and the forms timeout specified in web.config overrules the timeout which I set in FormsAuthenticationTicket. According the documentation, the timeout (expire date) in FormsAuthenticationTicket must override the timeout in web.config.

Documentation found on: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/910443
`If the ticket is generated manually by using the FormsAuthenticationTicket class, the time-out can be set through the Expiration attribute. This value will override the timeout attribute value specified in configuration files.`

Here is my code:

Web.config:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
 <forms 
  timeout="1" 
  loginUrl="login.aspx" 
  name="sessionTest" 
  cookieless="UseCookies" 
  defaultUrl="default.aspx"
 />
</authentication>
```

Login.aspc.cs:

```
FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(Login1.UserName, false, 2);
string encryptedTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);
HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encryptedTicket);
Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);

// redirect user
FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(Login1.UserName, false);
```

Now, when I login, i get redirected after 1 minute of inactivity. This isn't supposed to happen, right? I have to be redirected after 2 minutes.

Someone can explain this?

Answer (score 0):

I think the call to RedirectFromLoginPage is overwriting your cookie. You can try using this instead.

```
Response.Redirect( FormsAuthentication.GetRedirectUrl( UserName.Text, chkPersistCookie.Checked );
```

Additional information that might be useful here: https://web.archive.org/web/20210513002246/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/110701-1.3.shtml